# Is there an API for generating well-formed unmanaged C++ (similar to CodeDOM)?

Tags: c++, codedom

Is there any library or project out there that can give me an API to generate C++ code similarly to how CodeDOM does it?

Comment: "No" is a dangerous answer, but it certainly is 95% no.  Something like QT's Meta Object Compiler might qualify but that needs to start with you stating your framework requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There is a C++ CodeDom provider that is part of .NET 3.5. It's in a separate DLL, and not always mentioned with the VB and C# ones, so it can be hard to find. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualc.cppcodeprovider%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)